# c++ unordered_map for user defined data type

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I am writing this code for finding the connected components of a graph.

```
    using namespace std;
    struct node;
    typedef list<node> AdjList;
    struct node
    {
        bool visited;
        string  name;
        AdjList adjlist;
        node(string name1):name(name1),visited(false){}
        node(const string& a):name(a),visited(false){}
    };
    typedef node node;




    class graph
    {
    int nonodes;
    unordered_map<string,node> vertices;
    public:
    graph(int v):nonodes(v){}
    void addrelation(string a , string b);
    void addaccount(string name);
    void dfs();
    };

void  graph::addaccount(string name)
{
    unordered_map<string,node>::iterator it = vertices.find(name);

    if(it!=vertices.end())
    {
        cout<<"account already exists"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"creating a new account"<<endl;
        node* nnode=new node(name);
        vertices[name] = *nnode;
    }

}
```

For the lines,

```
    cout<<"creating a new account"<<endl;
    node* nnode=new node(name);
    vertices[name] = *nnode;
```

I get the below error.
toposort.cpp:72:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/tr1_impl/hashtable_policy.h:575: error: no matching function for call to ‘node::node()’

When we assign a already created member to a unordered_map,does the unordered_map internally try to copy it??

Comment: This got it working.                                                                  cout<<"creating a new account"<<endl;
  node* nnode=new node(name);
  std::pair<string,node> temp(name,*nnode);
  vertices.insert(temp);

Comment: i know it's not a refined code and the intention is not to refine it....the intention is to recollect the basics of graph theory and algorithms...not what is beautiful/not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. According to the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at)

> If an insertion is performed, the mapped value is value-initialized (default-constructed for class types, zero-initialized otherwise) and a reference to it is returned.

Internally, `std::unordered_map`'s `operator[]` needs to create a new instance of the data class when the key is not found, and return you a reference to it. All this happens before the assignment, while the left-hand side of the expression is being evaluated. That's what causing the error about the missing default constructor.

Hence, if you wish to use map's `operator[]` with your value type, you need to provide a way to default-construct your value object.

Note 1: Copying of the value does take place. However, it starts only *after* the `operator[]` returns.

Note 2: There is no point in defining a separate pass-by-value constructor for your `struct node`, because the other constructor (i.e. `node(const string& a)`) is perfectly capable of handling both cases.

Note 3: There is no point in allocating the node dynamically. Currently, it leaks memory. An assignment `vertices[name] = node(name);` would do the same thing without a leak.

Comment: There's also no point in dynamically allocating the nodes, since they have pure value semantics.  All his `new` is doing is leaking memory.

Comment: @JamesKanze Thanks! I added another note to mention this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The elements inserted with [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) in the `unordered_map` are value initialized:

> If an insertion is performed, the mapped value is value-initialized
>   (default-constructed for class types, zero-initialized otherwise) and
>   a reference to it is returned.

The element is then copied through the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

@dasblikenlight has partially explained the problem, but he didn't
present the solution.  The normal way of inserting an element is to use
the function `insert`:

```
vertices.insert( std::make_pair( name, node( name ) );
```

Since your `node` type has value semantics, you *shouldn't* `new` it,
just construct it when you need it.  If you really wanted to keep the
construction separate:

```
node newNode( name );
vertices.insert( std::make_pair( name, newNode ) );
```

(As a general rule, if a type has value semantics, it should never be
allocated dynamically.  There are exceptions, usually for performance
reasons, but they are just that, exceptions.)

Finally, `insert` inserts if and only if there is no element with the
equivalent key, and it returns a `std::pair` with a `bool` indicating
whether the insertion took place or not.  So your entire `addaccount`
becomes simple:

```
std::pair<std::unordered_map<std::string, node>::iterator, bool> results
    = vertices.insert( std::make_pair( name, node( name ) ) );
if ( ! results.second ) {
    std::cout << "account already exists" << std::endl;
}
```

(I'd normally use a typedef for the map type, to make such type names
more manageable.  Not to mention that it allows easily switching between
different types of maps; unless the map is very large, you may find
`std::map` preferable to `std::unordered_map`.)

Just to be clear about `[]`: the standard says that if the entry doesn't
exist, it inserts `value_type( key,  mapped_type() )` (using basically
the `insert` function above, where `value_type` is the `std::pair`).
That's where the invocation of the default constructor is occurring.
And... whether the insertion occurs is determined dynamically, so the
compiler will try and compile it, even if you never use `[]` on an
element which doesn't exist.  If you want to support `[]`, you must
support default construction of the mapped type.